# Can I program my Excel macro to write an AppleScript and store it in Excels Application Script folder?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, applescript

I am working on a project for that involves testing the limitations of macros in Microsoft Excel. My most recent portion of the project requires me to create an `AppleScript` in `VBA` and store it in Excel's Application Scripts folder in a Mac. However, this doesn't seem to work for me and I get a

> "Path/File Access Error"

I've already tried saving the file to another path on my computer (Using `"Application.DefaultFilePath & '/filename.applescript'"` which works fine). But when I change the path directory to my Application Scripts folder, it continues to give me a Path/File Access Error.

```
Sub WriteAppleScript()
   Dim newDir As String

   newDir = "/Users/myusername/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel/RunScript.applescript"

   Open newDir For Output As #2
   Print #2, "tell Application ""Terminal"""
   Close #2
End Sub
```

I expected this to write the file into the Application Scripts folder for Excel. But I got an error

> "Run-time Error '75'; Path/File Access Error"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really a VBA pro, but I suspect the problem in the space in the file path between "Application" and "Scripts". You might try using doubled quotes:

```
newDir = ""/Users/myusername/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel/RunScript.applescript""
```

or the equivalent:

```
newDir = char(34) & "/Users/myusername/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel/RunScript.applescript" & char(34)
```